# Mobile internet access and no static IP

Tags: networking, internet

Greeting. I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC and I use my mobile phone to access the internet. I have set a static IP on desktop. However, my IP does not stay static. I wonder why?

Comment: Assuming your computer is connected to your phone via WiFi (your phone acts as an access point) the phone will give a random "private IP" to your phone. Please note that every WiFi connection is a separate network and the IP address assigned to your computer will be different (separate) for each different WiFi network. The same can be said for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: If you are taking about a fixed local (private) IPv4 address for your computer, you can edit the settings of the relevant WiFi profile (the one you select to connect to your access point=phone) and specify a compatible (appropriate) private IPv4 address, network mask, etc. If you are talking about a static public (WAN) IP address, you should talk to your mobile internet access provider.